# Apache not rewriting, magento local copy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have a working Magento shop online. I'm trying to make it run locally as a copy for testing purposes. Everything works, except the url rewriting. I've already added the AllowOverride All option to my httpd config file, as everyone here suggested.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I also have RewriteEngine on in my .htaccess file (same htaccess as the online website). Still I'm getting the index.php 404 error on every other page than the homepage. http://www.example.com/index.php/randompage however **does** work. What's also strange is that the same configuration works for developer, but not for me. So it must be something apache specific I guess.

I've tried a lot of given suggestions in similar topics but nothing worked :(

Running macosx 10.9.5

I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do all pages with /index.php/ in the url work?  For example, **/index.php/customer/login**

Comment: Yes. I eventually 'fixed' it by installing and using apache2.4 via brew.

Answer (score 1):

You must have *mod_rewrite* enabled for apache.
Run `a2enmod rewrite` and then `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: a2enmod command not found. I guess it just enables LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so ? If so, I already had it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the RewriteBase parameter which may fix the issue.

In the `.htaccess` file in your Magento root on your local machine, look for the following:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

Change it to

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: it didn't change anything :(